# Is there a unique tool that displays results of both programming language and database in only one interface(gui)?

Tags: java, database

Are there any tools that display output of a line of code such as

[image: java code]

the output of the cellids that returns a string[] is being displayed here in the image above.

Similarly it should also display the database schema and results if possible of some queries we enter in that interface(gui) only.

Is there any tool that displays both like this in only one interface(gui)?

Comment: What you show on the image is a function of the eclipse debugger.
Are you looking for an eclipse plugin? Or something similar that can be used elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get Eclipse. If you're already using it, you can check out the Database Development perspective.

Comment: Thanks,iam already using it, but cannot see this database developement perspective in it.There are only java,plugin-in,debug etc.. perspective in it.Should i add some new plugins?

Comment: Then you should get the Eclipse IDE for JEE developers from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2).